# Nikon D5100: possible to get more than 30" exposure with self timer?

Tags: shutter-speed, nikon-d5100, bulb-mode, self-timer

Is there any way to increase the exposure time longer than 30" in the Nikon D5100? I know there is `BULB`, but is not working with self-timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a wired remote release that has a built in intervalometer, such as [this fairly inexpensive one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008FBMUMM) or [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0044QL3ES). Regardless of the brand name stamped on them, they all seem to be made identically.

[image]

You then set the camera to *Bulb* and let the timer in the remote open and close the shutter.